# how to get full path with a smb file name when using jcifs

Tags: java, samba, jcifs

I read the api of jCIFS about smbfile, but i haven't find out how to get the full smb path with just file name.
I want it returns "smb://aaa.bbb.com/sharedFolder/picture.jpg"
while it returns "smb://aaa.bbb.com/picture.jpg"
there is the code:

```
String user = "user";
String password = "password";
String sharedFolder = "sharedFolder/";
String path = "smb://aaa.bbb.com/";
String fileName = "picture.jpg";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", user, password);
SmbFile smb = new SmbFile(path, auth);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(smb, fileName);
//String canonicalPath = smb.getCanonicalPath(); 
String filePath = smbFile.getUncPath();
```

Comment: I believe the remote sees only the share name, not the name of the shared folder on the sharing system.

Answer (score 0):

Your arent't using the variable `sharedFolder` in your code. You could do,

```
String path = "smb://aaa.bbb.com/sharedFolder";
String fileName = "picture.jpg";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", user, password);
SmbFile smb = new SmbFile(path, auth);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(smb, fileName);
```

**or**

```
String sharedFolder = "sharedFolder/";
String path = "smb://aaa.bbb.com/" + sharedFolder; // <-- append it
String fileName = "picture.jpg";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", user, password);
SmbFile smb = new SmbFile(path, auth);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(smb, fileName);
```

Comment: Thank u all the way. Sorry, i didn't discribe my question clearly. i just know the file name and dont know where it is. i want jcifs returns the full path, like "pwd" command.

Comment: The `pwd` command tells you your present working directory. You're thinking of `locate` or `find`. You'd have to get the remote directory listing and hope it's a public folder, and recursively (or iteratively) *search* for matches.